# running program in computers without sql server

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to run a program in which a *SQL Server database* has been used in other computers where "**SQL Server**" has not been install?

Comment: Yes. The application must be configured to connect to a remote SQL server... (given that the network accessilibity is provided, of course)

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, you'd change the connection string to connect to a remote server like this:

```
Server=RemoteServerName;Database=DatabaseName;...
```

and in fact, that's the most common production configuration. A shared database amongst multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES. The only thing you need to do is to point where the Microsoft SQL Server is placed. Of course, you need to configure the server to accept remote connections and that the client you're tring to connect has internet access.

[Configure SQL Server to accept remote connections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)

Guessing that you use c#...

[Connection strings for c#](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

Comment: is there any way to do this without internet access (with local host)

Comment: @john: of course, but in that case you DO need to install SQL Server.